# Is possible change the IP of the Ingress?

Tags: kubernetes

Is possible to change the IP of the Ingress ?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  spec:
  defaultBackend:
service:
  name: test-reg
  port:
    number: 5000
```

now is assigned in automatic the 23 but I would like to change it and keep static

```
[ciuffoly@master-node ~]$ kubectl get ingresses
NAME           CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
test-ingress   <none>   *       192.168.1.23   80      5m9s
```

Comment: Hello, could you please add more detail to your question? I'd reckon this is possible but without the information about your setup it could be hard to point you to the right solution. Please tell how your Kubernetes cluster was created and which `Ingress controller` are you using.

Answer (score 2):

The possibility of "changing the IP address" will heavily depend on the Kubernetes solution used and how `Ingress` is handled within the cluster.

Having in mind the lack of the information about the setup it could be hard to point to the right direction. I've decided to post a community wiki answer to give more of a baseline idea and point where to look for possible answer.

Feel free to expand it.

---

If the Kubernetes cluster is managed (`GKE`, `EKS`, `AKS`) and you are using `Ingress` that is managed by your cloud provider, the best option would be to refer to its documentation on IP allocation. Some providers through `Ingress` annotations allow you to assign a specific IP address that was previously allocated (in `Web UI` for example).

If the Kubernetes cluster is provisioned on premise (`kubespray` or `kubeadm` or the `hard-way`) or it's something like `minikube`, `microk8s` or a `Docker Desktop` with Kubernetes it will still be the best course of action to check how it handles `Ingress` resource. There will be differences for example between the `kubespray` cluster with `metallb` and the `microk8s`.

What I mean by that is for the most part the `Ingress` resource is handled by an `Ingress controller` (a `Pod` or set of `Pods` inside the cluster). Depending on the solution used, it in most cases work like following:

- Resources are created for `Ingress` controller (`ClusterRoles`, `ValidatingWebhookConfiguration`, `RoleBindings`, etc.)
- `Service` of specific type (depending on the solution) is created to point to the `Deployment`/`Daemonset` that is an `Ingress controller` (like `nginx-ingress`, `kong`, etc).
- `Deployment`/`Daemonset` of an `Ingress controller` is created to receive the traffic and send it to `Services` that are specified in the `Ingress` resource.

**For IP address changing you would need to take a look specifically on the part of how this `Ingress controller` is exposed to the external sources and if/how you can alter its configuration.**

There will also be inherent differences between on-premise clusters created with `kubeadm`, `kubespray` and local development solutions like `minikube` and `Docker Desktop` with Kubernetes.

From my experience I've encountered `Ingress controllers` that were exposed either via:

- `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` - assuming that your setup allows for such `Service` you could use [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/)
- `HostNetwork` (binding to the port on a `Node`, hence using it's IP address)

---

Additional reference:

- *[Ibm.com: Cloud: Blog: Kubernetes Ingress](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/kubernetes-ingress)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)*